# Generating WAV File Tones

Tags: c#, audio, wav, trigonometry

I'm trying to programmatically construct an audio WAV file that contains *n* seconds of the standard UK ring ring tone that you hear when you dial a phone number.

I have [found a source](http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~fisher/telecom/tones/) that documents the frequencies and duration of the tone, which is a sine wave of two frequencies: 400Hz and 450Hz.

The code I have written generates a PCM WAV file in the correct format, which I can play using an audio player such as Windows Media Player, however the tone that it generates sounds like a much lower frequency than it should be, so don't think I've got the forumla quite right.

This is currently what I'm doing:

```
var duration = 10;
var bitsPerSample = 8;
var samplesPerSec = 8000;
var f1 = 400;
var f2 = 450;
var pattern = new[] {
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400),
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200),
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400),
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000)
        };

var wavdata = new byte[duration * samplesPerSec]; // 10 seconds of wav data @ 8000 samples per sec, 8 bits per sample, 1 channel 

// Loop through each sample
for (var i = 0; i < wavdata.Length; i = i + (bitsPerSample / 8)) {

    // Get time in seconds of the current sample
    var time = Convert.ToDouble(i) / (Convert.ToDouble(bitsPerSample) / 8) / samplesPerSec;

    // Calculate the on off pattern
    var onoff = 0;
    var timeMilliseconds = time * 1000;
    var p = 0;
    while (timeMilliseconds >= 0) {
        timeMilliseconds = timeMilliseconds - pattern[p].TotalMilliseconds;
        onoff = onoff == 1 ? 0 : 1;
        if (++p >= pattern.Length) p = 0;
    }

    // Calculate the sample: (sin(time * 400) * 128 + sin(time * 450) * 128)) / 2
    var sample = onoff * (((Math.Sin(time * f1) * 128) + (Math.Sin(time * f2) * 128)) / 2);

    // Store sample
    wavdata[i] = Convert.ToByte(sample + 128);

}
```

As you can see the formula I'm using is:

```
sin(time-of-sample * frequency) * amplitude
```

which I use twice for the two combined frequencies:

```
sin(time * 400) * 128
sin(time * 450) * 128
```

I then add them together and divide by 2 to get the average. I then multiply by 1 or 0 to get silence in between the tones to get the ring ring sound. And finially I offset the sample by 128 when I store the value in the data array as WAV file data is represented as plus or minus data.

What am I doing wrong? Why is the tone that this generates much lower in pitch than expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot Pi.  Sine cycles from 0...2π, not 0..1:

```
var sample = onoff * (((Math.Sin(2 * Math.Pi * time * f1) * 127) + (Math.Sin(2 * Math.Pi * time * f2) * 127)) / 2);
```

Also, notice that I changed the 128s to 127s because your float to byte conversion will overflow if your Sin gets too close to 1 or -1.  There's probably a better way to do this that doesn't sacrifice range but it probably doesn't matter for what you are doing.

If I may comment: The code does too many unit conversions.  Having time in both seconds and milliseconds is confusing.  And "sample" should range -1 to 1, then do the conversion to byte as a separate step.  By multiplying by 128 inside that line it mixes the concept of bytes in with the audio calculation which is a bit confusing.